# How to translate international (Lithuanian) characters to the correspondent HTML code in R?

Tags: r, encoding

Is there a way to read text from a text file and convert Latin-4 (ISO/IEC 8859-4) or Latin-6 (ISO/IEC 8859-10) characters to the correspondent HTML code *(and vice versa)* in R and RStudio, e.g. `ą` to `&261;`?

In particular I'm interested in coding-decoding these symbols: *Ąą Čč Ęę Ėė Įį Šš Ųų Ūū Žž*.
I was intending to use regular expressions for this task, but the first problem is that my RStudio does not even read the symbols correctly:

```
c("Ąą Čč Ęę Ėė Įį Šš Ųų Ūū Žž")
```

result is:

```
 [1] "Aa Cc Ee Ee Ii  Uu Uu ˇ˛"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best **R** package to read something with non-ASCII locales is [readr](https://github.com/hadley/readr/) from Hadley Wickham.

You could install it from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html) and check if it supports Latin-6